# Cannot assign value of type '() -> Void' to type '(() -> Void)!'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling

after updating to xcode 8 beta 6, I'm getting the error

> Cannot assign value of type '() -> Void' to type '(() -> Void)!'

on the following func block, third line:

```
    // Button sub-class
public class SCLButton: UIButton {
    var actionType = SCLActionType.none
    var target:AnyObject!
    var selector:Selector!
    var action:(()->Void)!

    public init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    }

    override public init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }

//    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
//        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
//    }
}
public func addButton(_ title:String, action:()->Void)->SCLButton {
    let btn = addButton(title)
    btn.actionType = SCLActionType.closure
    btn.action = action // here is where the error occurs
    btn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(SCLAlertView.buttonTapped(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
    btn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(SCLAlertView.buttonTapDown(_:)), for:[.touchDown, .touchDragEnter])
    btn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(SCLAlertView.buttonRelease(_:)), for:[.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside, .touchCancel, .touchDragOutside] )
    return btn
}
```

any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: The error message simply says that the expected type is `(() -> Void)!` (implicit unwrapped optional) but the type `() -> Void` (non-optional) is passed in the `action` parameter. The types don't match.

Comment: check updated question @ozgur

Comment: so what should i adjust? @vadian

Comment: I suppose the signature of the `action` parameter of `addButton` (the property `action` is not affected).

Comment: check updated question for more detail @vadian

Comment: What are you wanting to do? It's not right at all. Do you want something to happen when this `button` is added, like call a closure while you give a `title` to this button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your issue is related to this:
[SE-0103](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md)

Try chaging the method header of your `addButton(_:action:)` to:

```
public func addButton(_ title:String, action:@escaping ()->Void)->SCLButton {
```

The diagnostic messages from new betas are so confusing and inadequate as usual, but making your property simply non-Optional `var action:()->Void = {}` will give you a little more useful info.