# Cannot assign value of type '(Void) -> Void' to type '((Void) -> Void)?'

Tags: ios, swift, widget

The new Xcode Beta 6 produced this funny bug when I try to assign an empty closure to an optional closure variable as in:

```
var downloadHandler: ((Void) -> Void)?
func application(_ application:UIApplication, handleEventForBackgroundUrlSession identifier: String, completionHandler:(Void) -> Void){
    if identifier=="com.information.inarrivo.widgetBackgroundConfiguration"{
        self.downloadHandler = completionHandler
    }
}
```

Moreover I found this code in my project but I am not clear about who calls that function.

Comment: You need to mark the parameter `@escaping`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/39002126/2976878

Comment: @Hamish There should be a better error message for that :(

Comment: No. Writing the function like `func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventForBackgroundUrlSession identifier: String, completionHandler: ((Void) -> Void)) ` fixes the issue. See I've written the parameter `completionHandler`.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 No, that's a bug, see [SR-2397](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2397)

Comment: Yes, now it seems to compile correctly; yet I am not clear what is difference with my signature and yours. At any rate, who calls it? Putting override in front of it gives an error, so it must be part of a protocol, but I was not able to locate which among the ones I adopt contains it.