# Cannot convert value of type '() -> Void' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to fix my finale error whilst trying to convert to Swift 3, however I am unsure why I am getting the error

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> Void' to expected argument type '(()
>   -> Void)?'

For

```
 CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
```

Complete Function

```
fileprivate func deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [IndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation, duration: TimeInterval, completion:() -> Void) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion) //Error
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) { () -> Void in
        self.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: animation)
    }
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Does anybody know why I am getting this and how I can resolve the error ?

Comment: Are you sure that the message says "cover" and not "convert"?

Comment: @molbdnilo Oops my bad, it does say convert, must of misspelled and then spell check corrected to cover.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot assign value of type '() -> Void' to type '(() -> Void)!'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002126/cannot-assign-value-of-type-void-to-type-void)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please check [the latest reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/catransaction/1448281-setcompletionblock) when you find something odd in migrating your code to Swift 3.

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> class func setCompletionBlock(_ block: (@escaping () -> Void)?)
> ```

Try changing this part of your method header `completion:() -> Void` to this:

```
completion: @escaping () -> Void
```

Comment: Is it necessary to write `@ escaping `?

Comment: @technerd, yes. It's related to [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md). You need to propagate the requirement for `@escaping`, to help compiler to detect illegal usage for non-escaping (now it's become default) closures.